# Count no of month appear in Single column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Here in one column dates are in random order. I want to build query where it will count all the months how many times it appears.

SQL Table :-
EMP_table_date

```
    10/26/2014
    10/26/2014
    10/24/2014
    11/26/2014
    11/26/2014
    11/23/2014
    12/26/2014
    12/26/2014
```

Expected Output : -

```
Oct |   Nov |   Dec
3   |   3   |   2
```

Note:

1. Only single column mentioned above
2. Using Oracle 11G Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 1 then 1 end) as jan,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 2 then 1 end) as feb,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 3 then 1 end) as mar,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 4 then 1 end) as april,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 5 then 1 end) as may,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 6 then 1 end) as jun,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 7 then 1 end) as jul,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 8 then 1 end) as aug,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 9 then 1 end) as sep,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 10 then 1 end) as oct,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 11 then 1 end) as nov,
       count(case when extract(month from emp_table_date) = 12 then 1 end) as december
from emp_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRUNC(emp_table_date,'MON') as "MON",
       COUNT(emp_table_date)       as "CNT"
FROM   emp_table
GROUP BY TRUNC(emp_table_date,'MON');
```

This will return the count of each month in `rows`. Use standard `PIVOT` to convert it into `columns`.